# R - count at each row the number of columns in the "row neighbourhood" that contain only NA

Tags: r, apply

How would you create from a data frame a vector that gives for each row the number of columns that are "NA" (or a custom value) in that row and the *n* rows above and *m* rows below.

So if *m* = *n* = 1 (i.e. how many columns in each row are NA and have NA immediately before and after) and my dataframe is

```
structure(list(X = 1:8, A = c(3L, NA, 10L, NA, 6L, NA, 5L, NA
), B = c(6L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, NA, 13L, NA), C = c(NA, 12L, 14L,  
NA, NA, NA, 9L, NA), D = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11L, 7L, NA)), .Names = c("X", 
"A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

i.e.

```
 t X  A  B  C  D
1 1  3  6 NA NA 
2 2 NA NA 12 NA 
3 3 10 NA 14 NA 
4 4 NA NA NA NA
5 5  6  8 NA NA
6 6 NA NA NA 11
7 7  5 13  9  7
8 8 NA NA NA NA
```

I want the vector

```
count
0
1
2
1
1
0
0
0
```

(if the first and last entries are `NA`'s that's fine). I'm trying to mimic a `COUNTIFS` function in Excel, i.e. `COUNTIFS(B2:F2,"",B3:F3,"",B4:F4,"")` for row 3.

Comment: I don't understand how your description produces the desired result. How come that count has a 1 in row 2?

Comment: Column D has an NA in row 2 and in rows 1 and 3. The other columns don't, so `count` is 1 there.

Comment: @Henrik I *think* what they mean is: suppose we look at row `i` column `j`: if column `j` has NAs for the `n` rows before and `m` rows after row `i`, we count it. So for the second row, only the `NA` in the 'D' column has a `NA` immediately above and below it.

Comment: Yes, mathematical.coffee is correct.

Comment: @Hugh could I have a clarification - in row 1 the NA in column D has an NA after it but none before because there is no previous row - you want this to return 0 always? (i.e. the first and last elements of your `count` vector is always 0?)

Comment: Return 0 or `NA`, but I'm not fussed. The "true" value at that row is that the condition is meaningless, but I'm comfortable with 0. For higher *m* or *n* the same will be true for the first *n* and last *m* rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get what you mean.

Suppose the dataframe is called `x`.

First, for each (`row`, `colum`n) in `x`, we need to see if there is an `NA` in that cell, AND an `NA` in the *same column* for the `n` rows before and `m` rows after.

First, let's do this in the case of a single row, row `i = 2` say.
We also have `n = 1` and `m = 1` (from the example in the question).

```
i <- 2
n <- 1
m <- 1
```

Let's count the number of NAs in each column for rows `i - n` to `i + m` inclusive (`is.na` returns `TRUE` if the current value is NA, `colSums` gives column sums)

```
y <- colSums(is.na(x[(i - n):(i + m), ]))
# X A B C D 
# 0 1 2 1 3
```

Now we only have an `NA` in the previous, current, and next row if we counted 3 `NA`s (i.e. only column D qualifies here):

```
y == n + m + 1
#     X     A     B     C     D 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

so the *number* of columns that satisfy our criteria (hence the `i`th element of the output) is:

```
sum(y == n + m + 1)
# 1
```

We can then use `sapply` to apply this over each row:

```
countifs <- function (df, n, m) {
    sapply(1:nrow(df),
           function (i) {
               nrows <- nrow(df)
               startRow <- max(i - n, 1)
               endRow   <- min(i + m, nrows)
               y <- colSums(is.na(x[startRow:endRow, ]))
               sum(y == n + m + 1)
           })
}

countifs(x, 1, 1)
# [1] 0 1 2 1 1 0 0 0
```

You also mentioned that you might want to compare to a custom value rather than `NA`. In that case, instead of doing `is.na(x[...])`, you can just do `x[...] == value` (but not if `value` is `NA`, in which you use `is.na`)

Also, you could save a bit of work by only using `sapply` on rows `n + 1` to `nrow(df) - m - 1` and setting the first `n` and last `m` elements to 0 automatically.

Comment: All answers very helpful but this answered everything. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This should produce desired result -

```
y = is.na(yourDataFrame)

rowSums(y & rbind(rep(F,5), y[-nrow(yourDataFrame),]) & rbind(y[-1,], rep(F,5)))
```

Comment: Wow. I am impressed. Here is a version using `m` and `n`:
`rowSums(y & rbind(matrix(FALSE, nrow = m, ncol = 5), y[-((length(yourDataFrame)-(m-1)):length(yourDataFrame)),]) & rbind(y[-(1:n),], matrix(FALSE, nrow = n, ncol = 5)))`

Comment: @Henrik no, your version counts the number where the column `n` rows before and `m` rows after is NA, not where *all* rows from `n` before to `m` after are NA (in that column). Really like the slickness of this answer though unfortunately does not scale to arbitrary `n` and `m`

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Agreed. I missed that point in the description. And it seems difficult to adapt this solution to the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that will identify the `NA` values at the centre of a run of `length = .length`

```
foo <- function(x,.length){
  x <- is.na(x)
  if( .length < 2L ||.length %%2L == 0L ){stop('.length must be an odd number greater than 2')}
  lx <- length(x)
  if(lx <.length) {return(rep_len(FALSE, lx))}
  midpoints <- seq.int(2L, lx-1L, by = 1L)
  c(FALSE,sapply(midpoints, function(xx) all(x[(xx-1L):(xx+1L)])),FALSE)
}
```

We can use this with rowSums and `sapply` to get what you want.

```
rowSums(sapply(xx, foo, .length = 3))
## [1] 0 1 2 1 1 0 0 0
```

---

### without reinventing the wheel (something that rolls)

Or you could use `rollapply` from the `zoo` package

```
library(zoo)
rowSums(sapply(xx, function(x) {
    rollapply(is.na(x), width = 3, fill = FALSE, FUN = all)
   }))
```

or even just

```
rowSums(rollapply(is.na(xx),width=3, FUN=all, fill = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `describe` just to get the number of NAs in each column.

```
describe(traindata)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Column_3 
      n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90     .95 
    646      23     283  0.2792  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1455  0.4798  0.9305  1.0000
```

Check for `missing` values.

Comment: I don't think that will work for this. I need to know the row position of the NA condition, not just the total number of occurences of this condition for each column. Sorry, my title is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't come up with a vectorized version, so here is one using a good old for-loop:

```
x <- structure(list(X = 1:8, A = c(3L, NA, 10L, NA, 6L, NA, 5L, NA
), B = c(6L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, NA, 13L, NA), C = c(NA, 12L, 14L,  
NA, NA, NA, 9L, NA), D = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11L, 7L, NA)), .Names = c("X", 
"A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

y <- x
y[is.na(y)] <- -99
out <- vector("numeric", nrow(y))

n <- 1
m <- 1
for (c in (1+n):(nrow(y)-m)) {
    out[c] <- sum((y[(c-n),] == -99) & (y[(c),] == -99) & (y[(c+m),] == -99))
}
out
```

This should do the trick (even with allowing for n and m):

```
> out
[1] 0 1 2 1 1 0 0 0
```

Note that I use two tricks. As working with `NA`s is something problematic I exchange them with `-99` (although that isn't totally necessary). Then I do not loop over the first n and last m rows.

If somebody comes up with a vectorized version he/she gets definitely my upvote.

Comment: Yep, this solves the *n*=*m*=1 case. (The general case is probably asking too much.) Is there any particular reason why you chose -99?

Comment: As noted by mathematical.coffee above, the use of `m` and `n` here is not correct. use `rollapply` instead.